# Python Mysql, "commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Tags: python, mysql

I have a MySQL stored procedure that is executed from Python (wrapped in Django). I get the error "commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" when I try to execute the second statement. I cannot commit the transaction at this point. This is only an issue when I call a procedure. What to do?

```
cursor.callproc('my_mysql_procedure', [some_id,]) 
result = cursor.fetchall()
for r in result:
    do something

cursor.execute("select * from some_table")
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

EDIT: I've been asked to post the MySQL procedure. I have made it super-simple and I still see the same problem

```
delimiter $$
create procedure my_mysql_procedure(p_page_id int)
    begin

        select 1
        from dual; 

    end$$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: post your stored procedure code. that's where the problem is

Comment: In PHP, I had to clean/close the cursor after calling stored procecude in order to execute further sql code. Maybe this is the same issue.

Comment: JoshuaBoshi: That totally did the trick, thanks. cursor.close() and then open it again: cursor = connection.cursor()  Do you want to post it as the answer?

Comment: `select 1 from dual` is an Oracle-ism;  in mysql, just use `select 1`.

Comment: My problem was Threading. Without threading it worked perfectly, but using threads you also get such errors if threads are not well tracked by your own.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Thanks to JoshuaBoshi for his answer, which solved the problem. After calling the procedure, I had to close the cursor and open it again before using it to execute another statement:

```
cursor.close() 

cursor = connection.cursor()
```

The cursor can be closed immediately after `fetchall()`. The result set still remains and can be looped through.

Comment: That doesn't make sense - does anyone know why?

Comment: In addition, it should be pointed out that MySQLDB/SQLAlchemy cannot handle more than one query per string. That is
"select 1; select 1" will cause this problem.
TO MAKE MATTERS WORSE, *A COMMENT* can cause this too! SERIOUSLY!:
"select 1; -- whatever"

Comment: In my experience, I did not need to do this on my local computer, but when I ported the code to pythonanywhere, then I had to and it worked (+1).

Comment: mycursor.close() then mycursor = mydb.cursor() give me error... "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Cursor is not connected".

Comment: @Bonn Yo same, have you found a fix on that?

Answer (score 20):

The main cause of this is results that are not taken from the cursor before a new query is made. There may be multiple result sets.

To stop the error you must ensure you consume the result set each time with .nextset. If it produces multiple result sets- you may even need to do a few of them.

```
cursor.callproc('my_mysql_procedure', [some_id,]) 
result = cursor.fetchall()
for r in result:
    do something
cursor.nextset()
cursor.execute("select * from some_table")
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

In my case, I found that this can actually be an indicator of other problems in the sql queries that aren't picked out as python errors until a subsequent query is made. They produced multiple result sets.

Applying this to my example below (where I saw the same error),

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> conn = MySQLdb.connect(passwd="root", db="test")
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("insert into foo values (1););")
1L
>>> cur.nextset()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 107, in nextset
    nr = db.next_result()
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

Here - because a parsing error (some trusted input data, which was munged with code) lead to that semicolon and then a new statement - this produced multiple result sets. It will not produce an error for this statement, but for the next one that attempts to run a command on the cursor.

I've made a github repo - https://github.com/odmsolutions/mysql_python_out_of_sync_demo - to demonstrate and test this.

---

Original answer:
Take a look at https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/issues/28 for details on how I was able to reliably reproduce this with 3 lines of code:

Minimal case to reproduce this:
(assume you have a blank db, and have created only a connection to the db, called conn)

```
>>> conn.query("Create table foo(bar int(11))")
>>> conn.query("insert into foo values (1););")
>>> conn.query("insert into foo values (2););")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")
```

It is bad syntax which was generated and from the error I couldn’t tell that that was the problem.

Try examining the last query or procedure as Bukzor suggests - and try running it in a raw mysql client to see the real problem.

Comment: Hi thanks for this recomendation. I've tried increasing the buffer size, the timeouts... I was querying a select that sometimes returned a list instead of one row, then doing a fetchone seems to be leaving rows in the queue :O. Your answer helped me, now I do cur.nextset() before each new query.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a python issue, but a mysql issue. Do the same from perl and you will get the same error. In general, I see that message when I run a mysql console, then kill it from another console, then try to run a query from the killed console.

Something is killing your connection between statements. It's likely an error in your procedure. Check your mysql error log.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error when running the following Python (2.7) code:

```
  def _execute(self, query, params, is_destructive):
try:
  cursor = self.con.cursor()
  cursor.execute(query, params)
  if is_destructive:
    self.con.commit()
  return cursor.fetchall()
finally:
  cursor.close()
```

The problem stemmed from the self.con.commit() call. We were defensive, and coded to commit destructive (write) operations before closing the cursor. MySql did not like this. Removing the commit() called solved the problem and the script was still executed via cursor.fetchall()

Answer (score 2):

Since I have googled this few times now, landing on the same SO question (here), and none of the answers are helpful, here is protip for myself in the future:

this error is a source of unfetched response from MySQL. That is, we send request, and got something back but didn't care to read it.

```
req = "UPDATE data SET h1='qwertyuioasdasdasda' WHERE id=1;commit;"
```

In my case, after removing `commit` I was able to see this error:

```
Warning: (1265L, "Data truncated for column 'h1' at row 1")
```

It was raised because I was trying to write `h1` which was too long for data type. However, `commit` prevents me from getting this information back.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Mark Gerolimatos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729703/mark-gerolimatos)
mentioned in this thread`s comments, you cannot execute strings containing multiple sql commands, or even commands followed by a comment.

**This will NOT work:**

```
cursor.execute('SELECT 1; SELECT 2;')

cursor.execute('SELECT 1; -- myComment')
```

**This is fine:**

```
cursor.execute('SELECT 1;')
```

Comment: so, there is no way to execute any sql injection? If yes, I think this is pretty good. I tried to execute it and get this error.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting this error when i used a query to select one column data.. yet did not receive the error when I was selecting multiple columns.

This didn't work:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT PropID FROM for_sale WHERE redfin_rent_est is NULL")
```

This one did work- it did not create the commands out of sync error.

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT PropID, web_url FROM for_sale WHERE redfin_rent_est is NULL")
```

So apparently its caused my errors in syntax also?  I'm still unsure on the cause.