# Mysql + django exception: "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Tags: mysql, django, mysql-python, amazon-rds

Running django via gunicorn to RDS (AWS mysql), I'm seeing this error in my gunicorn logs:

```
Exception _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now") in <bound method Cursor.__del__ of <MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x690ecd0>> ignored
```

I can't reliably reproduce it yet, nor can I track down the underlying code that's causing it.

I am using raw cursors in some places, following this pattern:

```
cursor = connections['read_only'].cursor()
sql = "select username from auth_user;"
cursor.execute(sql)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
usernames = []
for row in rows:
    usernames.append(row[0])
```

In some places I immediately reuse the cursor for another query execute() / fetchall() pattern.  Sometimes I don't.

I also use raw manager queries in some place.

I'm not explicitly closing cursors, but I don't believe that I should.

Other than that: I'm not using any stored procedures, no `init_command` parameters, nor anything else indicated in the other answers I've seen posted here.

Any ideas or suggestions for how to debug would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this exception causing you any real problems other than showing up in the log?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, "commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583083/python-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now)

Answer (score -3):

Check out https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17289

you'll need to do something like:

```
while cursor.nextset() is not None:
    if verbose:                                                        
        print "rows modified %s" % cursor.rowcount
```

Comment: the question doesn't mention stored procedures at all (as does the ticket you refer).