# "Commands out of sync" without using cursor

Tags: mysql, django

We are getting these "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" errors in Apache from our Django application.  All my research on this says that it is an unclosed cursor connection that causes this ([previously here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583083/python-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now)) or the application is running multiple queries at the same time.

We are not using cursor connections anywhere outside of what's in the base django package, and I doubt those functions are being used.  Django should be handling any simultaneous query issues.  I have applied [this Django patch](https://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/17956/explicit_cursor_closing.patch) that should explicitly close any open connections, but no such luck.

Is this something to do with multi-threading?  Or just a general error in Django?

Comment: This is a MySQL error, not a django error. Something is closing your cursor commits between transactions, probably a misconfiguration. Have you checked your MySQL logs?

Comment: It is an error returned by MySQL, but it doesn't enter the MySQL logs. Like that of a syntax error or MySQL lock error.

Comment: What django version are you running, have you tried a recent vanilla install (*without* patches), are you using nasty `.extra()` or `.raw()` on your query sets, why do you think this isn't working for you, but does for everyone else? (what's unusual?)

Comment: Running 1.3.1.  It's an issue that only happens on production, not on dev, which makes it very difficult to track down.  Yes, we use raw() and extra() calls, mostly just for SELECT queries, which shouldn't cause sync issues, and Django should probably handle this.

Comment: We have not seen anything on the frontend, but we do run background tasks through the django ORM. That might explain why we don't see the errors.

Comment: This is turning into a discussion thread - maybe we should move it.. Sorry to rehash, but are you calling any custom stored procedures?

Comment: No stored procedures, triggers, or other DB level operations.  There might be something unique about what we're doing to cause these errors, but outside of cursor calls, I'm not sure what to look for.  Does Django not handle looping through save calls?