# Error 2014: Commands Out of Sync (Happens in one server but not another)

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli, prepared-statement

**Edit:**

Okay, so, I did a little more testing and found out it was stored procedures that mess everything up. But I don't know *why* stored procedures mess it up. See my first comment under this post for details.

**/Edit**

Okay, so, I've got this school project I've been working on using my laptop as a server. However, I cannot submit it without putting it on the school's servers. My lecturer finally gave me access to it and I finally was able to start migrating my project there.

After fixing a tonne of smaller issues like default charset mismatch and case sensitivity issues, this particular problem came along and has me stumped. I spent a few hours running through my code, looking through PHP documentation and mangling my code to print out walls of debug text and finally re-produced the bug with as little code as possible.

Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php
    define("HOST", "someHost");
    define("USER", "someUser");
    define("PASS", "somePass");
    define("DB"  , "someDB");
    $conn = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);

    $stmt1 = $conn->stmt_init();
    if (!$stmt1->prepare("CALL P_Topics_Get(33);")) {//If I uncomment this, I get an error when trying to prepare $stmt2
    //if (!$stmt1->prepare("SELECT * FROM Topics WHERE id = 33;")) { //If I uncomment this, I DON'T get an error anywhere
    //if (!$stmt1->prepare("SELECT 0, 'name', 1, 2, 3;")) {//If I uncomment this, I DON'T get an error anywhere
        echo "Failed to prepare 1: " . $conn->errno . ", " . $conn->error;
        exit;
    }
    if (!$stmt1->execute()) {
        echo "Failed to execute 1: " . $conn->errno . ", " . $conn->error;
        exit;
    }
    if (!$stmt1->store_result()) {
        echo "Failed to store 1: " . $conn->errno . ", " . $conn->error;
        exit;
    }
    $stmt1->bind_result($id, $name, $step, $decAmt, $maxAmt);
    if (!$stmt1->fetch()) {
        echo "Failed to fetch 1: " . $conn->errno . ", " . $conn->error;
        exit;
    }
    echo "$id, $name, $step, $decAmt, $maxAmt<br>";
    $stmt1->free_result();
    $stmt1->close();

    $stmt2 = $conn->stmt_init();
    if (!$stmt2->prepare("SELECT 2;")) {
        echo "Failed to prepare 2: " . $conn->errno . ", " . $conn->error;
        exit;
    }
    if (!$stmt2->execute()) {
        echo "Failed to execute 2: " . $conn->errno . ", " . $conn->error;
        exit;
    }
    if (!$stmt2->store_result()) {
        echo "Failed to store 2: " . $conn->errno . ", " . $conn->error;
        exit;
    }
    $stmt2->bind_result($val2);
    if (!$stmt2->fetch()) {
        echo "Failed to fetch 2: " . $conn->errno . ", " . $conn->error;
        exit;
    }
    echo "Val 2: " . $val2 . "<br>";
    $stmt2->free_result();
    $stmt2->close();

    echo "success";
?>
```

P_Topics_Get() is a simple select statement from a table:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Topics t
WHERE
  t.id = topicId;
```

So.. Yeah. This works on my localhost with no errors but messes everything up on the school's machine. This is the first time I have ever encountered the 2014 error.. And it's only 2013! (/joke)

Anyone know what's up?

Comment: I added this if-statement to the tests: `if (!$stmt1->prepare("SELECT * FROM Topics WHERE id = 33;")) { //If I uncomment this, I DON'T get an error anywhere`, with this if-statement (which is basically the stored procedure) it doesn't crash or show an error anywhere. I can conclude that the problem is with stored procedures.. Somehow. I'm just now sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, I found a workaround for it.
If you have a dbconfig.php file somewhere, add one simple function to it:

```
function reconnect () {
    global $conn;
    $conn->close();
    $conn = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
}
```

My dbconfig.php file looks like this:

```
<?php
    //Configurables
    define("HOST", "someHost");
    define("USER", "someUser");
    define("PASS", "somePass");
    define("DB"  , "someDB");
    //End Configurables
    $conn = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Server error: Please try again later.";
        //printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    function reconnect () {
        global $conn;
        $conn->close();
        $conn = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
    }
?>
```

Then, every time, after you call a stored procedure, call `reconnect()`!

```
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init(); //Old $conn
$stmt->prepare("CALL SomeProcedure();");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result();
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
reconnect(); //$conn is closed and re-opened

//$conn is a new connection
```

The thing is, in my case, if you call a *stored function*, you don't have to `reconnect()`.
As in, `SELECT F_SomeFunction();` does not require a `reconnect()` while `CALL P_SomeProcedure();` does.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to clean out more results, and/or close the cursor.

See: [Python, "commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583083/python-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now)

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php

Sorry, I'm not a PHP developer, so didn't bother to try it out.

Comment: I'm not using PDO, I'm using old mysqli. Also, I do call free_result() and close() which has the same effect as closeCursor(). Also, my stored procedure only ever returns one row, so it cannot be that there are still rows to fetch. Thanks for trying, though =x