# Why still has "commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" error

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am using Python mysqldb library to connect mysql db. I have a web server with 4 worker process which has **1 conn and 1 cursor** to mysql db. so every worker process will use its connection/cursor to execute sql sentence.

Now, I am have several client to simultaneously to send request to server, and server will query mysql db, and return some result to client. I encounter error. **2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"**
I have check sql, it just simple as `SELECT a, b, c from table WHERE a = 1`. There is no semicolon, or store procedure, and I also try below code as [Python, "commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583083/python-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now) suggest. but it still same error.

```
self.cursor.execute(sql, data)
self.conn.commit()
result = result + self.cursor.fetchall()
self.cursor.close()
self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
```

Comment: I know this might be a silly question but are you refreshing the cursor *before* the command and not just *after*?

Comment: It seems still has this error and some other errors.

Comment: HeyI have the same problem (I think). However I use the following type of code "cursor = mydb.cursor()", does this type of code use the same application of the connecting and committing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I fixed this issue. My app has multithread to use the same connection, it seems is not a proper way to access mysql, so when I do not share connection, the issue is gone.

Under 'threadSafety' in the [MySQLdb User Guide](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#functions-and-attributes):

> The MySQL protocol can not handle multiple threads using the same
>   connection at once. Some earlier versions of MySQLdb utilized locking
>   to achieve a threadsafety of 2. While this is not terribly hard to
>   accomplish using the standard Cursor class (which uses
>   mysql_store_result()), it is complicated by SSCursor (which uses
>   mysql_use_result(); with the latter you must ensure all the rows have
>   been read before another query can be executed. It is further
>   complicated by the addition of transactions, since transactions start
>   when a cursor execute a query, but end when COMMIT or ROLLBACK is
>   executed by the Connection object. Two threads simply cannot share a
>   connection while a transaction is in progress, in addition to not
>   being able to share it during query execution. This excessively
>   complicated the code to the point where it just isn't worth it.
>
> The general upshot of this is: Don't share connections between
>   threads. It's really not worth your effort or mine, and in the end,
>   will probably hurt performance, since the MySQL server runs a separate
>   thread for each connection. You can certainly do things like cache
>   connections in a pool, and give those connections to one thread at a
>   time. If you let two threads use a connection simultaneously, the
>   MySQL client library will probably upchuck and die. You have been
>   warned.