# CentOS server gunicorn [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I get this error in my Python Flask app when I deployed online. It is working on localhost but gives this error on the CentOS server.

```
 Exception _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; 
 you can't run this command now") in <bound method DictCursor.__del__ of 
 <MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor object at 0x1f7ead0>> ignored
```

I am trying to run this queries in a loop.

```
    g.db.autocommit(True)
    cur = g.db.cursor() 
    cur.execute("select * from users") 
    destinations = cur.fetchall()
    destinations = [customer.copy() for customer in destinations]
    for customer in destinations:
        cur.execute('select SUM(minutes) as minutes from details where code=%s', (customer['id'],))
        customer['minutes'] = cur.fetchone()
        cur.execute('select start from details where code=%s order by id limit 1', (customer['id'],))
        customer['start'] = cur.fetchone() 


    return json.dumps(destinations, cls=DateEncoder)
```

Comment: You might need to `cur.close()` at the end of your query http://stackoverflow.com/a/11590273/6085135

Comment: It works perfectly on my localhost but I get the error on my Linux server

Comment: Any difference in mysql configs?

Comment: I am accessing same online MYSQL database

Comment: The issue is when I try to loop through each customer in the dstination