# How to execute a .sql file using mysql connector and save it in a database in python?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a .sql file and I want to know if we can execute it directly in python using mysql.connector python class provided my mysql community.

Usually I can execute the .sql file in mysql server in terminal using these queries,

```
CREATE DATABASE test;
USE test;
source data.sql;
```

but I want to do it in python directly. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you just need to read the file then `execute` the string contents on the `cursor`... something like this

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  passwd="yourpassword"
)
with open('something.sql', 'r') as f:
    with mydb.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(f.read(), multi=True)
    mydb.commit()
```

Comment: thank you :) I just have two questions, will this work when my each sql-query is multi line? Also, how can I use (or) query the database (i.e I mean how can I check tables present what is the name of database created)?

Comment: Most .sql files contain more than one sql statement. For that to work from the python connector you'll be needing to set `multi=True` in the `execute()` method call. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: @O.Jones Thank you. Also how can I query the created database from the .sql file? I mean how can I use queries? For example how can I execute `show tables:` query? should I use mydb.execure('show tables:')

Comment: you would do the same thing `cursor.execute("some sql command")` but then you would need to `fetch` the results.  `results = cursor.fetchall()` here results should be an iterable you can look through

Comment: With MySQL 8.0.30, I have to exclude `mydb.commit()`. If I include `mydb.commit()`, then I get the error message `mysql .commit() is out of sync; you can't run this command now` ([this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583083/python-mysql-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now)). If I exclude `mydb.commit()`, then this approach seems to work.