# Python MySQL Commands out of sync even after opening a new cursor

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I have written a function to format and execute ***.sql*** files for me:

```py
def executeScript(pathToScript : str , connection : Conn.MySQLConnection , *args) -> list[tuple] | None:
    #executes a script
    connection.reconnect()
    cursor : Conn.MySQLCursor = connection.cursor()
    assert os.path.exists(pathToScript) , f"[{pathToScript}] does not exsist"
    with open(pathToScript , "r") as F:
        statement = " ".join(F.readlines())
    ... 
    format
    ...
    print(f"{'='*20}\nexecuteing:\n{statement}\n{'='*20}")
    cursor.execute(statement)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    assert cursor.close() , "cursor did not close properly"
    connection.commit()
    return data
```

This is the abbreviated function, I've taken out the formatting part because I know it works. whenever I call this it gives me this error:

```
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

Other posts say I need to open a new cursor but when I call this function it creates a new cursor and closes it when it is done.

In terms of SQL this is the script that it gets stuck on, the first one:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db;
USE db;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Profiles(
    PID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    discordID BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY(PID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Companies(
    CID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(PID) REFERENCES Profiles(PID), 
    CompanyName TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(CID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WorthHistory(
    CID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(CID) REFERENCES Companies(CID),
    created DATETIME NOT NULL,
    worth FLOAT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Shares(
    ShareID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    PID INT,
    CID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(PID) REFERENCES Profiles(PID),
    FOREIGN KEY(CID) REFERENCES Companies(CID),
    percent FLOAT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ShareID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BalanceHistory(
    PID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(PID) REFERENCES Profiles(PID),
    balance FLOAT NOT NULL,
    created DATETIME NOT NULL
);
```

I have run this script already and it does exactly what it's supposed to (as far as I can tell) so I don't think that's the issue.

I believe the problem is to do with `connection.commit()` as this is what I added before it broke. without the `.commit()` the function runs but no data is actually committed to the DB.

Comment: btw this is the post i looked at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583083/python-mysql-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now

Comment: Since the problem appears to be with the SQL you are trying to execute, there isn't much help we can give you if we can't see the SQL.

Comment: ill include the sql, but i dont think thats the problem, ive run each of the statements before but none of them were commiting so i included that connection.commit() you see and now i get this problem (ill also include that in the question)

Comment: "ther posts say i need to open a new cursor but when i call this function it creates a new cursor and closes it when its done" this suggests that the problem existed in the code prior to adding the new cursor in this function, so perhaps you need to share the previous version of the code?  It sounds like the connection has already emitted some statements and there is a conflict with what this function is doing.

Comment: the only difference between the previous version and this one is the line `connection.commit()` which i added becuase no data was actually being saved to the data base, after adding it i get the error. i think the code was always wrong somehow but the addition of connection.commit() caused the error to show up