# Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now, while trying to delete rows from a table by some condition

Tags: mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

I'm trying to delete rows from a table in the database according to a certain condition (in this case by a specific date)
This query works without any problem in MySQL workbench, but through Python, I get this error:
"Commands out of sync; you can not run this command now"

```
def delete_from_available_donations (self):
  self.cursor.execute("SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;\
                       DELETE FROM available_donations WHERE expiry_date = '2022-05-27'")
  res = self.connection.commit()
  return  1    

def main():
  q = DataQueries("root", "amitbrilant" , "Blood_bank") 
  q.delete_from_available_donations()
```

Answer (score 0):

As already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583083/python-mysql-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now) when you search your error message, you have to fetch results from the cursor first before you commit.

This also means that you have to split your statements into single executes to be able to free the cursor after each statement.

From my experience it is sufficient to split the statements and catch the result generator (`fetchall` is not necessary)

```
# ...
res = self.cursor.execute("YOUR SINGLE STATEMENT")
res = self.cursor.execute("YOUR SINGLE STATEMENT")
# ...
self.connection.commit()
# ...
```

This is diffrent for `mysql-connector` and `pymysql`. To be honest I don't know why...